# Customer name in newsletter subscription success email template

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, newsletter, email-templates

Im trying to include customer name in newsletter subscription success page. But I couldnt include customer name.

I have tried following variables in email template without successful. Im using magento 1.7.0.2

```
{{var customer.name}}
{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}
{{var subscriber.name}}
{{htmlescape var=$customer.firstname}}
{{var subscriber.CustomerFirstname}}
{{var subscriber.getCustomerFirstname()}}
{{var subscriber.getSubscriberFullName()}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get customer name by:

Rewriting a class Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber with your class.

Rewriting a function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail() in which you can get customer by:

```
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($this->getEmail());
```

and then assign variable 'customer' to email template

```
    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this, 'customer'=>$customer)
    );
```

- In newsletter_subscr_success.html you will have

```
   {{var customer.firstname}} {{var customer.lastname}}
```

or whatever you need from customer.